# How is 1 == [1] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coercion

Recently I have been asked this question in an interview.

```
 var a = 1;
 var b = [1];
```

What will `a == b;` return.

When I checked that on my chrome browser console I got this.

```
var a = 1;
var b = [1];
a == b;
true
```

I have also checked

```
var a = 1;
var b =(1);
a == b;
true
```

I know that *b* in an array of size 1. Does that mean that the size of array is assigned to b. I am really confused. Can anyone explain me the logic?

Comment: I don't know why you would be surprised about that example using  parentheses? If you wrote down the equation `(1) = 1` on a piece of paper, you would immediately say that the equation was true. Why do you think it would be otherwise when doing its equivalent in Javascript?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: however `a` is undefined in this case.

Comment: Here is one good article http://rainsoft.io/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/

Comment: @Paul I'm not talking about the original interview question, but the last example where the OP does `var b = (1);`.

Comment: @Paul I'm pretty sure OP means `var i = 1;` to be `var a = 1;` It would be a trivial interview question otherwise.

Comment: @Vucko: Exactly.  Sometimes the best interview questions are those that make sure the interviewee is paying attention. We use them all the time in every interview.

Comment: @nisar That's a bad edit: We don't know if this is the actual interview question or not - only the OP can fix this, if indeed it's broken. See the above comments discussion

Comment: @JamesThorpe I rolled back the edit for OP to edit him/herself.

Comment: @Paul: I m sorry it was my typing mistake. It should be var a = 1;

Comment: and this is why you should always use `===` instead of `==` unless you _really_ know what you're doing...

Comment: This is the sort of interview question that makes me cross. What earthly practical use is this knowledge?

Comment: There are plenty of weird things happening in js with the operators when the operands are of different type. see https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat for more fun stuff, and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 for the full spec of the `==` operation

Comment: That's type coercion at work. ECMAScript standard can explain the logic in finer details. Read it.

Comment: I agree Matt. If someone is bumping up across these quirks constantly to where they'd know the answer, I'd question how good they even are at programming.

Answer (score 56):

I didn't really understood from Rayon answer how `valueOf` and `toString` come into play when converting an object to a primitive value; so I dug into the [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) specifications.

**Warning**: Long answer.

We want to check the expression `1 == [1]`.

Starting from the **12.10 Equality Operators** we see that, after retrieving the expressions values, the last step is

> 7. Return the result of performing Abstract Equality Comparison rval == lval

*Abstract Equality Comparison* is defined at chapter **7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison**.

> 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison
>   The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. ReturnIfAbrupt(x).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(y).
> 3. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>      a. Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
> 4. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 5. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 6. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 7. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 10. **If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, then
>       return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).**
> 11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 12. Return false.

The expression `1 == [1]` falls under *case 10*.
So basically, as expected, the array `[1]` is converted into a value of primitive type.

*ToPrimitive* is define at **7.1.1 ToPrimitive ( input [, PreferredType] )**

> The abstract operation ToPrimitive takes an input argument and an optional argument PreferredType. The
>   abstract operation ToPrimitive converts its input argument to a non-Object type.

I haven't included the full quotation since the only interesting, **for this example**, parts are:

1. The *PreferredType* argument (actually an *hint* var) is converted from "default" (since it is not passed) to "number".
2. `OrdinaryToPrimitive` is called with the same arguments.

E now the interesting part, **OrdinaryToPrimitive** do the following:

> 1. Assert: Type(O) is Object
> 2. Assert: Type(hint) is String and its value is either "string" or "number".
> 3. If hint is "string", then
>      a. Let methodNames be «"toString", "valueOf"».
> 4. Else,
>      a. **Let methodNames be «"valueOf", "toString"».**
> 5. For each name in methodNames in List order, do
>      a. Let method be Get(O, name).
>      b. ReturnIfAbrupt(method).
>      c. If IsCallable(method) is true, then
>      ... i. Let result be Call(method, O).
>      ... ii. ReturnIfAbrupt(result).
>      ... iii. **If Type(result) is not Object, return result. **
> 6. Throw a TypeError exception

---

So in order to convert `[1]` to a primitive value, the runtime try first to call `valueOf`. This method returns the array itself, which is an object so by *5.c.iii* the method `toString` is called next.
 This method returns the elements of the array as a comma-separated list, so it just returns the string `"1"`.

So we are reduced comparing `1 == "1"` which by the rules of *Abstract Equality Comparison*, point 6, means to convert `"1"` into the number `1` and than performing the trivial comparison `1 = 1`.

The dubious reader is invited to check how **Strict Equality Comparison** is actually defined in the standard.

---

You can play with this conversions for better understanding them, here a sample playground HTML file

```
<html>
    <head><title>title</title></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var old_valueOf = Array.prototype.valueOf;
            var old_toString = Array.prototype.toString;

            Array.prototype.valueOf = function(){ console.log("Array::valueOf"); return old_valueOf.apply(this); };
            Array.prototype.toString = function(){ console.log("Array::toString"); return old_toString.apply(this); };

            console.log(1 == [1]); //Array::valueOf, Array::toString, true 

            Array.prototype.valueOf = function(){ console.log("Array::valueOf"); return 2; };

            console.log(1 == [1]); //Array::valueOf, false 

            Array.prototype.valueOf = function(){ console.log("Array::valueOf"); return {}; };
            Array.prototype.toString = function(){ console.log("Array::toString"); return {} };

            console.log(1 == [1]); //Array::valueOf, Array::toString, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! `1 == [1]` = `1 == [1].valueOf().toString()` = `1 == "1"` = `1 == 1`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Thanks, but my point is `1 == [1]` => `1 == [1].toString()` => `1 == "1"` = `1 == 1`

Comment: well, yea, but the valueOf is called none the less. I just tried to make the program flow insightful. Imagine having overwritten the valueOf method ;-)  `x = [1];x.valueOf = function(){return 'x';}`

Comment: I mean this :-) `x=[1];a=1;console.log(a==x);x.valueOf = function(){return 'x';};console.log(a==x);`

Comment: Great detailed answer `:)`

Answer (score 52):

> If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to convert the object to a primitive value, a `String` or `Number` value, using the [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) methods of the objects. If this attempt to convert the object fails, a runtime error is generated.[[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)]

```js
var a = 1;
var b = [1];
//What is happening when `(a==b)`
//typeof a;   ==> number
//typeof b;  ==>object
//Object is converted to Primitive using `valueOf` and `toString` methods of the objects
var val = b.valueOf().toString();
console.log('Values after conversion is: ' + val + '  And typeof converted value is:  ' + typeof val);
//typeof val; ==> string
//a == b; will be evaluated as `true` because `'1' == 1` hence..
console.log(a == b); //'1'==1 ==> true
```

As converted value is of type `String`, *When comparing a `number` and a `string`, the `string` is converted to a `number` value and then strict comparison is applied.*

Comment: So it means `[1]` is converted to string `"1"` that is converted to integer `1`? Is that right?

Comment: No - read the comments in the OP.

Comment: If you look more closely, a is undefined; the original value defined is actually **i**.

Comment: what does it mean `JavaScript attempts to return the default value for the object.` What is default value in above case?

Comment: The one thing that doesn't make sense to me is that you've directly casted the primitive value of b to a string in the line `var val = b.valueOf().toString();`, therefore `console.log(typeof val)` is going to surely return `string`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paul, That was just to demonstrate the the evaluation of `'1' == 1 ==> true`..

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString()` should be the only standard for type checking, as `typeof` is [flawed](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/). I understand what you're doing though.

Answer (score 13):

This is due to the type of comparison being made.

In javascript, one can use either `==` or `===` for comparison. In the case of a triple equals, this is what's known as [equality *without* type coercion](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html), in other words, it's a strict comparison.

**Equality with type coercion**

Conversely, this means that using the double equals operand is equality *with* type coercion.

**What does this mean?**

Simply put, it means that javascript will use in-built methods in order to convert the value to a primitive type, ready for comparison. Specifically, those methods are `.valueOf()` and `.toString()`.

Here are some examples:

```
0 == false   // true, auto type coercion
0 === false  // false, because they are of a different type
1 == "1"     // true, auto type coercion
1 === "1"    // false, because they are of a different type
```

Ergo:

```
1 == [1] // true
1 === [1] // false, because they are of a different type
```

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be much appreciated, I will happily ameliorate my answer if there's something which would add to its value.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing it was due to only covering that type conversion is going on and not explaining how `[1]` becomes `1` when the type conversion happens. +1 though for showcasing the difference between `==` and `===`

Comment: I suppose if you're to take to the question literally, the OP did say 'how', however I thought that was possibly a language barrier issue and the question was actually more of a 'why', given that s/he was asked this by an interviewer whom I assume was probing for this exact knowledge. (More so I'd expect than _how_ javascript fundamentally handles this nuance.) Still, I thought the other answerers did a good job of explaining that and I didn't want to copy! Thanks for your feedback @jdkorv11 :)